# Nested mysql select statements

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query as below:

```
$sult = mysql_query("select * from stories where `categ` = 'businessnews' and `stryid`='".mysql_query("SELECT * FROM comments WHERE `comto`='".mysql_query("select * from stories where `categ` ='businessnews'")." ORDER BY COUNT(comto) DESC")."'  LIMIT 3") or die(mysql_error());
                while($ow=mysql_fetch_array($sult)){
```

The code above should return the top 3 'stories' with the most comments {count(comto)}. The comments are stored in a different table from the stories. The code above does not return any values and doesn't show any errors. Could someone please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing query to MySQL server so let it do its job.

```
SELECT
   *,
   (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM comments WHERE `comto` = WHERE story_id = s.id) as commentsCount
FROM stories s
WHERE
   s.categ = 'businessnews'
ORDER BY commentsCount DESC
LIMIT 3
```

Comment: Be explicit:  you intend for the entire string to be passed in as opposed to any nested prepared statements, right?

Comment: @Makoto I think that I can't be more explicit. Also, there is nothing about prepared statements in question or in my answer (but surely OP should use them). I just suggested that executing query, getting results in PHP and passing them back to database doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score -1):

Use subqueries for this work...
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/subqueries.html